# Flink's aggregateFunction's getResult() function not been called

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-flink

When I use .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10))) or .countWindow(100), the .aggregate function is perfectly executed, but when I use .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10))), I can't get any output.

By printing out the data in each function, I found that createAccumulator() and add() have been called, and every 10 seconds createAccumulator() is called again, the contents of the accumulator are also counted from zero.
this should prove that the window closed properly and a new window opened, but why getResult() function not been called.

I set the Watermark in the following way

```
outputStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
                    WatermarkStrategy.<GatewayLogCv>forMonotonousTimestamps()
                            .withTimestampAssigner(new GatewayTimeStampAssigner()));


##GatewayTimeStampAssigner.java
public class GatewayTimeStampAssigner implements SerializableTimestampAssigner<GatewayLogCv> {

    @Override
    public long extractTimestamp(GatewayLogCv gatewayLogCv, long l) {
        AppLog.i("waterMark is " +gatewayLogCv.getLogTimeMs());
        return gatewayLogCv.getLogTimeMs();
    }
}
```

getLogTimeMs() returns like that

```
waterMark is 1653643704219
waterMark is 1653643690969
waterMark is 1653643706464
waterMark is 1653643694129
waterMark is 1653643691571
```

and I use .window() like that

```
dataStream
       .keyBy(new KeySelector<GatewayLogCv, String>() {
            @Override
            public String getKey(GatewayLogCv gatewayLogCv) {
                return gatewayLogCv.getGatewayCode();
            }
        })
       .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10)))
       .aggregate(new TotalAggregateFunction());
```

I don't know what's wrong, or is the StreamExecutionEnvironment missing some settings?

This problem has been bothering me for days. If someone can help me, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider:

(1) By using `forMonotonousTimestamps` you are asserting that the events will be processed in order, by timestamp. However, the timestamps printed out in your example are not in order. If those lines were all printed by the same thread/task, then you need to use a different strategy.

(2) Event time windows are triggered by watermarks. For a given window to close you have to have an event from the following window (or even later than that, depending on how much delay you use in your watermark strategy), because only such an event will cause a large enough watermark to be created. Perhaps you didn't supply enough data to trigger any windows.

(3) When operating in parallel, the overall watermark is the minimum of the various watermarks. A single idle partition can prevent windows from closing. If this is an issue, use the `withIdleness` option on the `WatermarkStrategy`.

Comment: Thanks for your help，I've replaced forMonotonousTimestamps  with forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(5))， and add.withIdleness(Duration.ofSeconds(2)) on the WatermarkStrategy.  I switched to Kafka as the data source, had about 100 entries per second from the service to the Kafka, and set Flink's parallelism to 1 to prevent idle partitions. But unfortunately, getResult() is still not called. Now I'm paying attention to when createAccumulator() and getResult() will be called.

Comment: I'm sure all my data has the same EventKey, so I key() this value to make sure I only have one window at a time. I added the log to the add() method and found this output. `log_time_30s=1653908865012, cntInfo=571, 
log_time_30s=1653908865012, cntInfo=572,  
log_time_30s=1653908865012, cntInfo=572,  
log_time_30s=1653908879909, cntInfo=1, 
log_time_30s=1653908879909, cntInfo=2, 
log_time_30s=1653908879909, cntInfo=3, 
log_time_30s=1653908879909, cntInfo=4, 
log_time_30s=1653908865012, cntInfo=573,`

Comment: I always thought createAccumulator() would create a new accumulator when watermaker exceeded this window, and getResult() would return the old accumulator. But the reality is that the new accumulator is created, but the old accumulator appears to be processing late data.  I didn't add .allowedlateness(), which I knew would extend the window's existence Time to process late data, but even if I added it and set the parameter to time.seconds(2), it didn't make any difference.